# Ember Model Computed Property Not Working

Tags: mongodb, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I have a module logging errors on my MEEN stack app. I have a model for my ember route that pulls in data from my express server via mongoose.

I wanted to alter the date property on my model to format the date differently from how it is stored in the mongo database to save some real estate on the page ie: Tue Sep 19 2017 16:57:17 GMT-0400 (EDT) to 2017-09-19.

I followed the Ember docs for computer properties on the model but the template is not displaying the computed value.

model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'Ember';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  error: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.attr('string'),
  module: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('string'),
  smallDate: Ember.computed('date', function() {
    var dateObj = new Date(this.get('date'));
    return `${dateObj.getFullYear()}-${dateObj.getMonth()}-${dateObj.getDate()}`;
  })
});
```

template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
    <h2 class="toolTitle">Blame Panel</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Error</th>
        <th>Component</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each model as |blame index|}}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{index}}</th>
          <td>{{blame.user}}</td>
          <td>{{blame.error}}</td>
          <td>{{blame.module}}</td>
          <td>{{blame.smallDate}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If I just use the date property of the model it displays the unformatted date fine.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it should be working. What behavior are you seeing instead?

Another option that may fit your setup better is to move that formatting concern out into a helper. If you do `ember g helper format-date` then you can use that same approach to formatting your date in a variety of places like this:

```
{{format-date blame.date}}
```

Comment: i'm just getting no return value in the template at all. I checked ember inspector and the property isn't showing up in the model at all.

Comment: I would suggest testing things in a unit test then (either of the helper approach or of your model). I find it is really helpful for tracking down these bugs, as you can then add a `debugger` statement to see what is going on

Comment: thanks for the advice ill try unit testing it this will bug me to no end if i don't figure it out now